# column is not the same length or scale as referencing column

Tags: c#, database-migration, entity-framework-migrations

I am getting error on migration builder that one column is not the same length or scale as referencing column.

[image]

above is the table I am trying to have migration builder create and it is complaining about the UserId.

This is my migration builder code for both tables.

```
migrationBuilder.CreateTable(
                name: "AspNetUsers",
                columns: table => new
                {
                    Id = table.Column<string>(nullable: false),
                    UserName = table.Column<string>(maxLength: 256, nullable: true),
                    FirstName = table.Column<string>(maxLength: 256, nullable: true),
                    LastName = table.Column<string>(maxLength: 256, nullable: true),
                    NormalizedUserName = table.Column<string>(maxLength: 256, nullable: true),
                    Email = table.Column<string>(maxLength: 256, nullable: true),
                    NormalizedEmail = table.Column<string>(maxLength: 256, nullable: true),
                    EmailConfirmed = table.Column<bool>(nullable: false),
                    PasswordHash = table.Column<string>(nullable: true),
                    SecurityStamp = table.Column<string>(nullable: true),
                    ConcurrencyStamp = table.Column<string>(nullable: true),
                    PhoneNumber = table.Column<string>(nullable: true),
                    PhoneNumberConfirmed = table.Column<bool>(nullable: false),
                    TwoFactorEnabled = table.Column<bool>(nullable: false),
                    LockoutEnd = table.Column<DateTimeOffset>(nullable: true),
                    LockoutEnabled = table.Column<bool>(nullable: false),
                    AccessFailedCount = table.Column<int>(nullable: false),
                },
                constraints: table =>
                {
                    table.PrimaryKey("PK_AspNetUsers", x => x.Id);
                });
```

this is the aspnet users table then this is the organization table

```
migrationBuilder.CreateTable(
                name: "Organization",
                columns: table => new
                {
                    OrganizationId = table.Column<int>(nullable: false)
                        .Annotation("SqlServer:Identity", "1,1"),
                    DistrictId = table.Column<int>(nullable: true),
                    Name = table.Column<string>(nullable: true),
                    Address1 = table.Column<string>(nullable: true),
                    Address2 = table.Column<string>(nullable: true),
                    City = table.Column<string>(nullable: true),
                    State = table.Column<string>(nullable: true),
                    Zip = table.Column<string>(nullable: true),
                    Country = table.Column<string>(nullable: true),
                    County = table.Column<string>(nullable: true),
                    Latitude = table.Column<string>(nullable: true),
                    Longitude = table.Column<string>(nullable: true),
                    TimeZone = table.Column<string>(nullable: true),
                    UserId = table.Column<string>(nullable: true),
                    OrganizationLogo = table.Column<string>(nullable: true),
                    SubscriptionId = table.Column<int>(nullable: true),
                    DateAdded = table.Column<DateTime>(nullable: true),
                    DateDeleted = table.Column<DateTime>(nullable: true),
                    DateUpdated = table.Column<DateTime>(nullable: true),
                    UpdatedBy = table.Column<string>(nullable: true),
                    AddedBy = table.Column<string>(nullable: true),
                    DeletedBy = table.Column<string>(nullable: true),
                },
                constraints: table =>
                {
                    table.PrimaryKey("PK_Organization", x => new {x.OrganizationId });
                    table.ForeignKey(
                        name: "FK_Organization_District_DistrictId",
                        column: x => x.DistrictId,
                        principalTable: "District",
                        principalColumn: "DistrictId",
                        onDelete: ReferentialAction.Cascade
                    );
                    table.ForeignKey(
                        name: "FK_Organization_AspNetUsers_UserId",
                        column: x => x.UserId,
                        principalTable: "AspNetUsers",
                        principalColumn: "Id",
                        onDelete: ReferentialAction.Cascade
                    );
                    table.ForeignKey(
                        name: "FK_Organization_Subscription_SubscriptionId",
                        column: x => x.SubscriptionId,
                        principalTable: "Subscription",
                        principalColumn: "SubscriptionId",
                        onDelete: ReferentialAction.Cascade
                    );

                });
```

I tried setting userid nullable to false on organization table and it does not help. I am not sure what to do here to make the relationship I am wanting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It may be because the columns are being created with different nvarchar lengths. Try specifying the maxLength as 450 for your PK/FK columns in the migration.

Comment: yes this was correct even though it does not give a max length identity framework is doing it behind the scenes I had to figure that out